# how to do queries to txt file using windows mobile? i dont find odbc for windows mobile

Tags: windows-mobile, odbc, oledb, oledbconnection, handheld

I have a file, which I am able read with a windows application using `odbc driver`,

File :-

```
col1, col2, col3, col4
1,2,3,4
a,b,c,d
e,f,g,h
5,6,7,8
1,b,2,c
```

I need read it with a HandHeld with Windows Mobile. I have sqlce but I dont find odbc driver for windows mobile. How can I do queries to text files? Earlier I read it line by line and inserted it onto a database; but now I have to do this process using a odbc connection. Is it possible?

Comment: The text file is on a handheld.  Where do you want to do the processing?  On the handheld also, or on a PC connected to the handheld?

Comment: i need do this process on the handheld

Comment: You may have to read your text file with a [StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx) and pick out your entries to populate your data into a [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows CE/Windows Mobile has no ODBC support at all. That means that for text file access you have to open the file with something like a `TextReader` and manually parse the file with `ReadLine` and `string.Split`.

You might consider a third-party wrapper like the SDF's [`TextDataAdapter`](http://www.opennetcf.com/library/sdf/html/d12ac962-39b7-f6ce-36ae-b83ae4681f68.htm), which does the parsing for you and will push the text into a `DataSet` but it really depends on the complexity of what you want to do.